# How to change the axis of rotation

Tags: android-animation, android-canvas, android, android-custom-view

I want to flip image view on axis which is 45 degree left or right from Y axis. How can I obtain this new axis of rotation and how can I apply it to image view. Here is the link
of what I want to achieve.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hDlp-aWq-uM&feature=youtu.be

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use [Camera](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Camera) to achieve 3D rotation like View.setRotationY.

```
camera.save();
camera.rotateY(rotate);
camera.getMatrix(matrix);
matrix.preTranslate(-left, 0);
matrix.postTranslate(left, 0);
camera.restore();

canvas.save();
canvas.concat(matrix);

canvas.drawBitmap(...);

canvas.restore();
```

The result for my personal project can be viewed below.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with Matrix class

```
Matrix mtrx=new Matrix();
imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);  
mtrx.postRotate((float) angle, pivX, pivY);
imageView.setImageMatrix(mtrx);
```

Comment: I have tried this but not able to change the axis with this, can you help what could be angle,pivX,pivY in my case?

Answer (score 0):

you should override draw method or create your own image view class by extending ImageView, then to rotate the axis rotate the canvas in draw(), and for the flipping you can user objectanimator which is available for API 11+, and for pre-11 you can user nineoldandroids.com library located at below url

http://nineoldandroids.com/

Comment: thanks for the response Onur, but rotating the canvas will not change the axis of rotation it will just rotate the view.

Comment: rotate the canvas, draw the animation then restore the canvas, so this way it works :)